# Draw temperature maps multiple times after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, heatmap

I'm doing a hobby project. I load every 2 hours a temperature map with different values (points). I get problems with DrawLow function. Drawing temperature maps multiple times after each other gives rare problems. He remembers his color values. How can I change the color values / polygons, etc. reset so it renders well.

If you reload the page, then it solves the problem.
But without reloading this bugs appears! and i don't want to reload my page!

I have emailed the author of the library. He has uploaded a new update, but the problem is not yet solved.

What I've tried myself:
Clear the canvas: `ctx0.clearRect(0, 0, can0.width, can0.height);`

Reload the temperatureMap.js: `$('#temperatureMapScript').remove(); $.getScript("Scripts/temperatureMap.js", function () { $('script:last').attr('id', 'temperatureMapScript');`

Reload the canvas: `$("#canvast1").load(location.href + " #canvast1");`

The code i'm using is:

```
var can0 = document.getElementById("canvast1"); // Get the canvas object
var ctx0 = can0.getContext("2d");           // Get the canvas context
    var drw0 = new TemperatureMap(ctx0);        // Create the object 
    ctx0.clearRect(0, 0, can0.width, can0.height); //Clear the canvas!
dataSet.d.forEach(function(dataSet) {
        listPoints.push(dataSet);
    });
  drw0.setPoints(listPoints, 500, 500);
    drw0.drawLow(5, 8, true, function () { // 5 = Number of closer influent points
        // 8 = Quality parameter [2, 32]
        //false = clean polygon outside
    drw0.drawPoints();    
    });
```

I think this bug has to do with the canvas createRadialGradient / color element.  Can anyone help me out to reset properly the canvas?

[First time run(good one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxJoe.png)
[Second time run(buggy one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoBuS.png)

Comment: Note: temperature map library link: https://github.com/optimisme/javascript-temperatureMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue

The draw low method (in the temperatureMap library) must include this lines, because the canvas element remembers the previous state!.

```
ctx.width += 0;   //Resizing the canvas will cause the canvas to get cleared.
ctx.fillStyle = "#191919"; //must be filled white for properly rendering before setting the gradient
```